# Algorithms in front of the text!

Tags: algorithm2e

I am writing a document using the `book` class.

At some point, I need to place an algorithm in the text. I am using the `algorithm2e.sty` package to write my algorithms.

So, I write

```
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\mbox{\textbf{KeyGen($\lambda$)}}
  \\$sk \xleftarrow{\$} (2\mathbb{Z} + 1) \cap [2^{\eta-1},\;
  2^{\eta})$\\
  \Repeat{$x_{0}$ for ímpar $[x_{0}]_{r}$ for par}{$x_{i}
    \xleftarrow{\$} D_{\gamma,\rho}(p)$ em $i = 0,...,\tau$}
  $pk = \langle x_{0},x_{1},...,x_{\tau} \rangle$
\end{algorithm}

\end{minipage}
&

\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\mbox{\textbf{Encrypt(pk,m)}}
 \\escolher um subconjunto aleatório $S \subseteq \{ 1,2,...,\tau \}$\\
 $r \xleftarrow{\$} (-2^{\eta},\; 2^{\eta})$\\
 $c \gets [m + 2r + 2\sum_{i\in S}x_i ]_{x_{0}}$
\end{algorithm}

\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\mbox{\textbf{Decrypt(sk,c)}}
 \\$m' \gets (c\; mod\; sk)\; mod\; 2$
\end{algorithm}

\end{minipage}
&

\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\mbox{\textbf{Addition($c_{1},c_{2}$)}}
 \\$c \gets c_{1} + c_{2}$
\end{algorithm}

\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}{0.2\linewidth}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\mbox{\textbf{Multiplication($c_{1},c_{2}$)}}
 \\$c \gets c_{1} \cdot c_{2}$
\end{algorithm}

\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
```

But, when I compile it, the algorithms appear in front of the text! How do I fix this?

Best regards!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

As an optional argument for the `algorithm` environment you can use one of `Hhtbp`, in a similar manner you use them in the `figure` environment.

The `H` and `h` arguments force the algorithm to stay in place, but if you use `H` the algorithm **is no more a floating object**...

So, probably you wanted to use `h` and not `H`.

### EDIT

I modified the last code you provided as MWE. See if it is OK or use it as a start point

```
\begin{algorithm}[h]
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\mbox{\textbf{KeyGen($\lambda$)}}
  \\$sk \xleftarrow{\$} (2\mathbb{Z} + 1) \cap [2^{\eta-1},\;
  2^{\eta})$\\
  \Repeat{$x_{0}$ for ímpar $[x_{0}]_{r}$ for par}{$x_{i}
    \xleftarrow{\$} D_{\gamma,\rho}(p)$ em $i = 0,...,\tau$}
  $pk = \langle x_{0},x_{1},...,x_{\tau} \rangle$
\end{minipage}
&

\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\mbox{\textbf{Encrypt(pk,m)}}
 \\escolher um subconjunto aleatório $S \subseteq \{ 1,2,...,\tau \}$\\
 $r \xleftarrow{\$} (-2^{\eta},\; 2^{\eta})$\\
 $c \gets [m + 2r + 2\sum_{i\in S}x_i ]_{x_{0}}$
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[h]
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
\mbox{\textbf{Decrypt(sk,c)}}
 \\$m' \gets (c\; mod\; sk)\; mod\; 2$
\end{minipage}
&

\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
\mbox{\textbf{Addition($c_{1},c_{2}$)}}
 \\$c \gets c_{1} + c_{2}$
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}{0.2\linewidth}
\mbox{\textbf{Multiplication($c_{1},c_{2}$)}}
 \\$c \gets c_{1} \cdot c_{2}$
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: It outputs an error when I change it for h... I am putting the algorithms in a minipage by the way

Comment: Can you add some more code to your MWE?

Comment: I have added more code to the question

Comment: Yes, that's because you can not put floats neither inside `minipage` nor `tabular` environments. One way is to reverse the order of the environments (e.g. switch `minipage` and `algorithm`), but in your case is a bit complicated because you have 3 levels...

Comment: But I have another document, with exactly the same example, with the algorithms inside minipages and it works perfectly!

Comment: It happens when you have `H` because in this case `algorithm` is not a float, if you change it to `h` it becomes a float.

Comment: It outputs an error if I change it to h

Comment: As I said already, with `h` it becomes a float and cannot be inserted inside a `minipage` or a `tabular`...

Comment: See the edit in my answer